# ListView addition of the sum of numbers in lines

Tags: c#, listview

Please help with the code. How can you add numbers from 3,4,5 columns and transfer it to the "Total" column. At the same time, the "Total" column cannot be permanent, for example, listView1.Items [i] .SubItems [11] .Text - this solution is not appropriate, you need to possibly find the "Total" column itself because it is not permanent It can be like SubItems [ 9] 10.11, etc.

Code to write data to listView1

```
      dataReader = await cmd1.ExecuteReaderAsync();

        if (dataReader.FieldCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        listView1.Columns.Add(dataReader.GetName(0), 0, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listView1.Columns.Add(dataReader.GetName(i).ToString().Replace("_", " "), 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                    }
                }

                ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
                //
                while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    lv = listView1.Items.Add(dataReader[dataReader.GetName(0)].ToString().Replace('_', ' '));
                    for (int h = 1; h < dataReader.FieldCount; h++)
                    {

                        lv.SubItems.Add(dataReader[dataReader.GetName(h)].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                listView1.Columns[i].Width = -2;
```

Comment: *you need to possibly find the "Total" column* Then access it by name and not by index

Comment: so I ask how to do it ))

Comment: like `listView1.Items [i].SubItems ["Total"]`

Comment: @Rahul How can you add the number of rows from 3,4,5 columns and transfer it to the "Total" column. Pls сod ))
I'm just a novice

Comment: Help pls   --- error cod     for (int itt = 1; itt < listView1.Items.Count; itt++)
                {
                   
                        int Totall = 20;

                        //Сумма чисел добавить во всего
                        listView1.Items[itt].SubItems["Total"].Add(Totall);
                    

                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes there is a column named "Total" in `listView1`.

```
(int itt = 1; itt < listView1.Items.Count; itt++)
{
    int Totall =
        int.Parse(listView1.Items[itt].SubItems[2].Text) +
        int.Parse(listView1.Items[itt].SubItems[3].Text) +
        int.Parse(listView1.Items[itt].SubItems[4].Text);

    //Сумма чисел добавить во всего 
    listView1.Items[itt].SubItems["Total"].Text = Totall.ToString();
}
```

`int.Parse` converts a string to an integer but keep in mind it will throw an exception if the string is not numerical. If you need error checking for that consider using `int.TryParse`.

Also note that SubItems are 0 indexed. Meaning 0 corresponds to the first visual column, 1 corresponds to the second.